# Разделить string на HTML элементы

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Хотел разделить `string` на html элементы `span`.

Т.е, что бы

из `<div>Самсунг, Айфон</div>`

в

```
<div>
  <span>Самсунг</span>
  <span>Айфон</span>
</div>
```

Comment: иии в чем вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
let str = div.textContent;
div.textContent = '';
let arr = str.split(',');


arr.forEach(i => {
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = i;
  div.appendChild(span);
})
```

```html
<div>Самсунг, Айфон</div>
```

Comment: Почти самый оптимальный вариант, на мой взгляд. Только не стоит добавлять элементы `span` сразу в `div`, который на странице. Можно создать контейнер ` document.createDocumentFragment()` и добавить в него все `span`'ы, а потом через `appendChild`, разом добавить все элементы на страницу

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам !